# Maximum of an annotation after a group by

Tags: python, django

I would like to compute the maximum of `a_priority` for each group of `(b, c)` pairs.

`a_priority` is an annotation based on a case/when mapping strings to priority values.

```
from django.db.models import Max, Case, When, IntegerField
qs = MyObject.objects.all()
qs = qs.annotate(
    a_priority=Case(
        When(a='A', then=1), 
        When(a='S', then=2),
        When(a='Q', then=3),        
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )
)
qs = qs.values("b", "c").annotate(Max("a_priority"))
```

I get the following error:

```
KeyError: 'a_priority'
```

I believe the `qs.values("b", "c")` filters out my annotation `a_priority`. Behavior is different with any actual field, providing the max of the field.

My django version is 1.10 on python 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried putting `Case` expression directly into `Max`? It is possible [since Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#expression).

```
from django.db.models import Max, Case, When, IntegerField
qs = MyObject.objects.all()
a_priority=Case(
    When(a='A', then=1), 
    When(a='S', then=2),
    When(a='Q', then=3),        
    output_field=IntegerField()
)
qs = qs.values("b", "c").annotate(max_a_priority=Max(a_priority))
```

Answer (score 1):

> I believe the `qs.values("b", "c")` filters out my annotation `a_priority`.

You are correct! `values` constrain the columns that are returned in the resulting QuerySet. But since the QuerySet is linked to the original model, you can filter using columns not provided in `values` (ex: `qs.values('b', 'c').filter('a'='A')`).

The best way to accomplish your task is Piotr Ćwiek's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40318163/maximum-of-an-annotation-after-a-group-by/40418387#40418387). But to make the answers more comprehensive (and to get to know aggregations better):

- explicitly include `a_priority` in your `values`:

  ```
  qs1 = qs.values("b", "c", "a_priority").annotate(max_priority=Max("a_priority")).distinct()
  # Or
  qs2 = qs.values("b", "c", "a_priority").annotate(max_priority=Max("a_priority")).filter(a_priority=F('max_a_priority'))
  ```
- reverse the order of `values` and `annotate`:

  ```
  qs3 = qs.annotate(max_priority=Max("a_priority")).values("b", "c").distinct()
  ```

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses) explain why `distinct` (or `filter`) is required here, and not in Piotr's answer:

> If the values() clause precedes the annotate(), the annotation will be computed using the grouping described by the values() clause.

So `a_priority` is also included in the `GROUP BY` clause in `qs1` and `qs2`, hence `distinct` is required.

> However, if the annotate() clause precedes the values() clause, **the annotations will be generated over the entire query set**. In this case, the values() clause only constrains the fields that are generated on output.

This explains `qs3`. Internally, Django does `GROUP BY` by `id` to get results over the entire QuerySet.