# Calculate Max of Sum of an annotated field over a grouped by query in Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm, aggregate

To keep it simple I have four tables(A, B, Category and Relation), Relation table stores the `Intensity` of A in B and Category stores the type of B.

> A <--- Relation ---> B ---> Category

(So the relation between A and B is n to n, when the relation between B and Category is n to 1)

I need an ORM to group Relation records by Category and A, then calculate `Sum` of `Intensity` in each (Category, A) (seems simple till here), then I want to annotate Max of calculated `Sum` in each Category.

My code is something like:

```
 A.objects.values('B_id').annotate(AcSum=Sum(Intensity)).annotate(Max(AcSum))
```

Which throws the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot compute Max('AcSum'): 'AcSum' is an aggregate
```

[Django-group-by](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-group-by) package with the same error.

For further information please also see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43007595/aggregation-of-an-annotation-in-group-by-in-django).

I am using Django 2 and PostgreSQL.

Is there a way to achieve this using ORM, if there is not, what would be the solution using raw SQL expression?

#### Update

After lots of struggling I found out that what I wrote was indeed an aggregation, however what I want is to find out the maximum of AcSum of each A in each category. So I suppose I have to group-by the result once more after AcSum Calculation. Based on this insight I found a [stack-overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40318163/maximum-of-an-annotation-after-a-group-by) which asks the same concept(The question was asked 1 year, 2 months ago without any accepted answer).
Chaining another values('id') to the set does not function neither as a group_by nor as a filter for output attributes, It removes AcSum from the set. Adding AcSum to values() is also not an option due to changes in the grouped by result set.
I think what I am trying to do is re grouping the grouped by query based on the fields inside a column (i.e id).
any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do an aggregate of an aggregate `Max(Sum())`, it's not valid in SQL, whether you're using the ORM or not. Instead, you have to join the table to itself to find the maximum. You can do this using a subquery. The below code looks right to me, but keep in mind I don't have something to run this on, so it might not be perfect.

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef

annotation = {
    'AcSum': Sum('intensity')
}
# The basic query is on Relation grouped by A and Category, annotated
# with the Sum of intensity
query = Relation.objects.values('a', 'b__category').annotate(**annotation)

# The subquery is joined to the outerquery on the Category
sub_filter = Q(b__category=OuterRef('b__category'))
# The subquery is grouped by A and Category and annotated with the Sum
# of intensity, which is then ordered descending so that when a LIMIT 1
# is applied, you get the Max.
subquery = Relation.objects.filter(sub_filter).values(
    'a', 'b__category').annotate(**annotation).order_by(
    '-AcSum').values('AcSum')[:1]

query = query.annotate(max_intensity=Subquery(subquery))
```

This should generate SQL like:

```
SELECT a_id, category_id,
       (SELECT SUM(U0.intensity) AS AcSum
        FROM RELATION U0
        JOIN B U1 on U0.b_id = U1.id
        WHERE U1.category_id = B.category_id
        GROUP BY U0.a_id, U1.category_id
        ORDER BY SUM(U0.intensity) DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS max_intensity
FROM Relation
JOIN B on Relation.b_id = B.id
GROUP BY Relation.a_id, B.category_id
```

It may be more performant to eliminate the join in `Subquery` by using a backend specific feature like `array_agg` (Postgres) or `GroupConcat` (MySQL) to collect the `Relation.ids` that are grouped together in the outer query. But I don't know what backend you're using.

Comment: Thank you for your time and insight. You made my day! @Brad Martsberger

Comment: You are going to claim the award in six hours.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work for you. I couldn't test it myself, so please let me know the result:

```
Relation.objects.annotate(
   b_category=F('B__Category')
).values(
   'A', 'b_category'
).annotate(
   SumInensityPerCategory=Sum('Intensity')
).values(
   'A', MaxIntensitySumPerCategory=Max('SumInensityPerCategory')
)
```

Comment: Thanks, however I get the same error:
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot compute Max('SumInensityPerCategory'): 'SumInensityPerCategory' is an aggregate
@Ahmad