# How to use PostgreSQL ArrayAgg function on a grouped by query set in Django ORM?

Tags: django, postgresql, performance, join, array-agg

To keep it simple I have four tables(A, B, Category and Relation), Relation table stores the Intensity of A in B and Category stores the type of B.

```
A <--- Relation ---> B ---> Category
```

I am trying to eliminate joins in my query to reduce calculations time using PostgreSQL's ArrayAgg and indexing feature of the database based on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/martsberger/c9971b553738869a87af29f52c4085cd). (Since there are 18000 relations, 4000 Bs, and 1500 categories my calculations of each report would take almost two hours)
and the error I get is:
    psycopg2.ProgrammingError: aggregate functions are not allowed in GROUP BY
LINE 1: ... U0."id", U2."B" HAVING U0."id" = ANY((ARRAY_AGG(...

I have used [Brad Martsberger solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48253635/3993575) to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226944/calculate-max-of-sum-of-an-annotated-field-over-a-grouped-by-query-in-django-orm) to calculate sum of each A's intensity occurred in B grouped by B's categories,
Minimum and Maximum of calculated Intensity-sums in each category of B and the rate of occurrence of each A in each B category and the occurrence of B itself in that category :

```
annotation0 = {
        'SumIntensity': Sum('ARelation__Intensity'),
        'A_Ids': ArrayAgg('id')
    } 
annotation1 = {
        'BOccurrence' : Count('id', distinct=True),
    }
sub_filter0 = Q(id__any=OuterRef('A_Ids'))
sub_filter1 = Q(Category_id=OuterRef('ARelation__B__Category_id'))
subquery0 = A.objects.filter(sub_filter0).values('id','ARelation__B__Category_id').annotate(**annotation0).order_by('-SumIntensity').values('SumIntensity')[:1]
subquery1 = A.objects.filter(sub_filter0).values('id','ARelation__B__Category_id').annotate(**annotation0).order_by('SumIntensity').values('SumIntensity')[:1]
subquery2 = B.objects.filter(sub_filter1).values('Category_id').annotate(**annotation1).values('BOccurrence')[:1]
result = A.objects.values(
        'id','id','ARelation__B__Category_id'
    ).annotate(
        **annotation0
    )
result = result.annotate(MaxAIntensity=Subquery(subquery0))
result = result.annotate(MinAIntensity=Subquery(subquery1))
result = result.annotate(BOccurrence=Subquery(subquery2))
result = result.annotate(
        AOccurrence=Count('id', distinct=False)
)
```

How can I resolve the issue?

Is there any other efficient alternatives to this?

Comment: Well, I think you should try to use window expressions https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions

Comment: Thank you for the insight @Basalex. Is it possible to pass A_Ids (ArrayAgg('id')) to as an partition_by argument? I see that it's not filterable, does it mean that filtering the query have no effect on function?

Comment: Well, I suggest use window expressions instead of grouping by. But it`s just a suggestion. I`m not 100% sure. I`ve not tried to use ArrayAgg with partition_by, so have no idea about it, but I don`t think it will work.

Comment: Thank you anyway @Basalex, I'm going to give it a try and post you up.

Comment: Ок, I`m curious about the result

Comment: Using Window, I get the error:
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot compute Max('SumIntensity'): 'SumIntensity' is an aggregate.

It seems it can't handle aggregation over annotated sum in partition which was the reason why we used Subquery at first place and I don't see a way to use aggregate and [:1] in window.
Any thoughts? @Basalex