# using Filtered Count in django over joined tables returns wrong values

Tags: django, orm, count, distinct, aggregation

To keep it simple I have four tables(A, B, Category and Relation), Relation table stores the Intensity of A in B and Category stores the type of B.

```
A <--- Relation ---> B ---> Category
```

(So the relation between A and B is n to n, where the relation between B and Category is n to 1)

What I need is to calculate the occurrence rate of A in Category which is obtained using:

```
A.objects.values(
    'id', 'relation_set__B__Category_id'
).annotate(
    ANum = Count('id', distinct=False)
)
```

Please notice that If I use 'distinct=True' instead every and each 'Anum' would be equal to 1 which is not the desired outcome. The problem is that I have to filter the calculation based on the dates that B has been occurred on(and some other fields in B table), 
I am using django 2.0's feature which makes [using filter as an argument in aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations) possible.
Let's assume:

```
kwargs= {}
kwargs['relation_set__B____BDate__gte'] = the_start_limit
```

I could use it in my code like:

```
A.objects.values(
    'id', 'relation_set__B__Category_id'
).annotate(
    Anum = Count('id', distinct=False, filter=Q(**kwargs))
)
```

However the result I get is duplicated due to the table joins and I cannot use distinct=True as I explained. (querying A is also a must since I have to aggregate some other fields on this table as explained in my [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226944/calculate-max-of-sum-of-an-annotated-field-over-a-grouped-by-query-in-django-orm))

I am using Postgres and django 2.0.1 .

Is there any workarounds to achieve what I have in mind?

**Update**

Got it done using another Subquery:

```
# subquery
annotation = {
    'ANum': Count('relation_set__A_id', distinct=False, 
    filter=Q(**Bkwargs),
}
sub_filter = Q(relation_set__A_id=OuterRef('id')) & 
Q(Category_id=OuterRef('relation_set__B__Category_id'))
# you could annotate 'relation_set__B__Category_id' to A query an set the field here.
subquery = B.objects.filter(
    sub_filter
).values(
    'relation_set__A_id'
).annotate(**annotation).values('ANum')[:1]

# main query
A.objects.values(
    'id', 'relation_set__B__Category_id'
).annotate(
    Anum = Subquery(subquery)
)
```

Comment: You write that you need "the occurrence rate of A in Category". I understand that you want a list of certain Category-objects (filtered by `B.date`), each annotated with an `Anum` attribute. Not a list of A-objects with an `Anum`attribute that your query creates. Can you clarify this?

Comment: Sure. I need a list of A objects grouped by its 'id' and the Category table with an annotated field (Anum) which represents the number of occurrence of B in A in a certain category.
for example risk (A) is high (intensity) in Accident (B) in a certain Route-Part (Category). If I want to know the probability of a certain risk in a Route-Part I need to Count the Risk's occurrence number in Accidents that happened on that certain Route-Part and divide it by the total Accidents in that Route-Part. @ascripter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure if I understood what you want. You write

> Please notice that If I use 'distinct=True' instead every and each 'Anum' would be equal to 1

Of course. You count the associated A-object to each A-object. Each counts itself. So I still think you don't want to annotate A-objects with `Anum`, but probably Categories. This one should give you the desired number of As in each Category.

```
Category.objects.annotate(
    Anum=Count(
        'b__relation__a',
        filter=Q(b__BDate__gte=the_start_limit),
        distinct=True
    )
)
```

`'b__relation__a'` follows the [relations backwards](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards) and picks all A-objects that are related to the Category. However the filter limits the counted relations to certain Bs. The `distinct=True` is needed to avoid a [query bug](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations).

If you really want "a list of A objects grouped by its id" (and not only the aggregated `Anum`-count), as you stated in your comment, I don't see an easy way to do that in a single query.

Comment: Please notice that without the filter argument using distinct=False, I get the desired result, I need to filter my input data which is being feed to calculation. I have applied the approach you proposed using Subquery() without any luck. Going to update the question with the code.

Comment: OK. I got it done using distinct=False starting from B table.
going to update my question with the approach.

Comment: I have updated the question. However the problem with filtration persists which I asked in a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48742045/how-to-avoid-duplication-in-filtering-a-field-in-a-medium-table-n-to-n-relation).