# Query to categorize a model by the number of foreign key items

Tags: django

I have the following models:

```
Family():
  family_id = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=100)

Individual():
  individual_id = models.TextField(db_index=True)
  family = models.ForeignKey(Family, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

I need to write a query to get the following result:

```
Family Count | Individual Count
1            |      3 
5            |      8 
10           |      19
```

So, I need to categorize families (not as their family_ids, but as their **counts**!) by the number of individuals they have. Is it possible? And if yes, how?

So far I am able to get how many individuals each family_id has:

```
overview_data = Family.objects.annotate(ind_count=Count('individual')).order_by('ind_count')
```

Now I need a way to sum them up by the number of individuals their groups have.

Comment: which field in Family needs be grouped by for counting?

Comment: Please, see the answer. No field to group by, it should be grouped by the number of individuals present, summing up families.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I was able to solve it not through `SQL` query, but using python. I would believe there can be purely `SQL` query but I was not able to come up with it. So, if you have any ideas, please, answer. Here is how I solved the issue:

```
from collections import Counter 

def _generate_overview_data(project):                                                                                      
    data = Family.objects.annotate(ind_count=Count('individual'))                                                                     
            .values_list('ind_count', flat=True)                                                     
    return sorted(Counter(data).items())
```

`data` looks like `[1, 1, 1, 1, ..., 2, 2, ..., 3, 3, 3, ...]`
So, I count the number of occurrences of 1, 2, 3 and get the ordered list of type `[[1, 89], [2, 10], ...]` where `89` families have `1` individual, `10` families have `2` individuals, etc.; and thats' what I would prefer to get straight from `SQL`.

Comment: oh. give you a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226944/calculate-max-of-sum-of-an-annotated-field-over-a-grouped-by-query-in-django-orm/48253635), hope you can got the trick, or based your list result, you can use itertools.groupby to solve it.